# How to find the minimum distance in a Poisson Point Process?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let us consider a Poisson Point Process (PPP) $\Phi$ of density $\lambda$.

The region is a unit circle (radius=1).

If there is a point $o\notin\Phi$ (not belonging to the poison process) in the centre, how to find the minimum distance from the point $o$ to the closest point $z$ belonging to the PPP, i.e., $z\in\Phi$ for different $\lambda$?

Note: The distribution of the distance between the point $o$ and $z$, i.e.,$r=\|o-z\|$ is given by $$2\pi\lambda r\exp(-\pi\lambda r^2)$$

For example, I want $r_{\min}$ in terms of a numerical value or an expression. Lets say $r_{\min}=0.12$. Expectation will also be fine.

Comment: Since the closest point is random, rather than finding the minimum distance one might seek the probability distribution of the minimum distance. $\qquad$

Comment: One complication is that since the area is finite, the number of points falling in the region may be $0$.  How does one then define the minimum distance? $\qquad$

Comment: Over infinite region, $P(d>r)=\exp(-\lambda\pi r^2)$, hence $d$ is Rayleigh distributed with $\sigma^2=\frac 1{2\lambda\pi}$. You can suit this to finite regions as well.

Comment: The mean is $\frac 1{2\sqrt\lambda}$

Comment: Why is $d$ Rayleigh distributed here?

Answer (score 3):

First I'll do this on the whole plane.  Let $R$ be the distance from the origin to the nearest point in the process.  Then
\begin{align}
& \Pr(R \ge r) \\[6pt]
= {} & \Pr(\text{the number of points in the process at distance $<r$ from the origin} = 0) \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac{(\lambda\cdot\text{area})^0 e^{-\lambda\cdot\text{area}}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda\pi r^2}. \tag 1
\end{align}
From this you can find the c.d.f. and the p.d.f.

Now let's assume the support is a disk. Here I'm tempted to say $R=\infty$ if the number of points or the process that are within the disk are $0$.  Alternatively, one could plausibly say it is the radius of the disk.  In that case $(1)$ would hold for $r\le\text{the radius}$ and you've have to work piecewise; you'd have a mixture of discrete and continuous distributions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have edited my question. Please have a look at it. If you have more suggestions, please!