# Finding density of the distance from an arbitrary starting point to the nearest tree

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, density-function

> Trees in a forest are distributed according to a Poisson process. Let $X$ be the distance from an arbitrary starting point to the nearest tree. Given that the average number of trees per square metre is $\lambda,$ find the density $f(x)$ of $X.$

The probability that there are $0$ trees within a circle of radius $x$ from the starting point is $e^{-\lambda \pi x^2},$ since $\lambda \pi x^2$ is the average number of circles that would be expected in that region. But I'm not sure how to relate this to $X,$ the distance from an arbitrary starting point to the nearest tree. Fix a starting point $S.$ If the distance from $S$ to the nearest tree is $x,$ then doesn't that mean that there's at least one tree within that distance of $x$? If so, then the probability of the nearest tree being a distance of $x$ from the starting point should be the probability of at least one tree occurring in the circle of radius $x,$ which is $1-P(no \,trees\, occur).$ This is the cumulative distribution function as it's the sum of the probabilities that the nearest tree is a distance of $0\leq y\leq x$ from the start point, and so to find the density, we just take the derivative.

> Is this correct?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have said looks correct to me but does not seem answer the original question:

- The expected number of trees within $x$ of the point is $\lambda \pi x^2$
- The probability there is *exactly* one tree within $x$ of the point is, as you say,  $\lambda \pi x^2 e^{-\lambda \pi x^2}$ as this is a Poisson process, but this is not particularly helpful
- The probability there are no trees within $x$ of the point is $e^{-\lambda \pi x^2}$ as this is a Poisson process
- The probability there is *at least* one tree within $x$ of the point is $1-e^{-\lambda \pi x^2}$ and this is a cumulative probability
- The density for the distance of the nearest tree is then $2 \lambda \pi x e^{-\lambda \pi x^2}$ by taking the derivative